# How do C and C++ Standard Library functions find the end of a file?

Tags: c++, c, file-io, filesystems, std

How do `fseek(myFILEptr, 0, SEEK_END)` and `myifstream.seekg(0, std::ios::end)` work?

Do they have to inspect every character and is their time complexity linear with the size of the file? Is it more intelligent than that? What information does a typical filesystem provide to work with?

Which parts of this are addressed by the language standards and which are not? For the parts that are not in either standard, are there de facto standards?

I grouped C and C++ together here because I expect the answer for each to be nearly identical or even that the C++ functions could and might often be implemented in terms of the C functions. Is that correct?

Comment: Typically, these functions would delegate to the operating system the program is running on. A typical operating system would provide a way to quickly seek to an arbitrary offset in the file, hardware permitting (tape drives are one example of hardware with slow seeks). No particular complexity guarantees are provided by C or C++ standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice, language implementations rely on the OS to deal with this (which in turn relies on the filesystem).  For example, POSIX provides the [`lseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lseek.html) syscall.

Thus they can't make any guarantees about complexity; they're dependent on the OS/hardware implementation.

Comment: They're also allowed to fail, which they might do if the "file" turns out to be a FIFO.